# incompatible type address in android

Tags: java, android

I have tried a lot in removing the error but unable to remove one error that is incompatible type address

```
   public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
EditText ed;
Button btn;
private GoogleMap mMap;
List<Address> addressList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);



    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


public  void  onsearch()
{
    String location=ed.getText().toString();


    if(location!=null|| !location.equals("")){
        Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(this);
        try {
          addressList=geocoder.getFromLocationName(location,1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address=addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng=new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    }




}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

please help as in error dialog box shows
.dialog box shows found android.location.address requires List import com.google.android.gms.identity.intents.Address

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the wrong import statement. It would be helpful if you provided the error stack trace and the full source including imports though.

Comment: In import com.google.android.gms.identity.intents.Address exists but it creates incompatable error still as i use the address list statement

Comment: Yea I don't believe you want that import. Geocoder returns android.location.Address you either need to import that or explicitly declare your address variables.

Comment: yeah i have used geocoder still import is not happening in addresslist statement can you give an alternative to this if yes please show

Comment: If you're not going to fix your import statements you need to do
List<android.location.Address> addressList;

and

android.location.Address address=addressList.get(0);

Comment: What you have told me  right now does not work I have tried a lot doing this if some alternative more please let me know

Comment: Thanks it worked in a new activity ...cant say why it was not working in old one thanks once again